# Configurable Application Insights Instrumentation Key

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-application-insights

How can I best make the Application Inisghts' Instrumentation Key configurable in a way that allows an Azure Administrator to manage the settings for an App Services deployment of an MVC5 web application? Is there a certain event in an MVC application initialization where this should be done or is it okay to do it at pretty much any point? I am using the Trace Listener integration as well.

By default, the Instrumentation Key (iKey) is set in the `ApplicationInsights.config` file. Additionally, if you include the JavaScript portions, the iKey is again set in the `_Layout.cshtml` file. This is two different places with an iKey that you need to manage.

I want to be able to manage this key via the **App Services** -> **Application settings** tab of the Azure Portal. The reasons are:

1. I want to deploy multiple instances of this applications, each with its own unique iKey
2. I want to change this iKey periodically (because *reasons*)
3. I don't want this iKey stored in our code repository (it's okay for a "dev" iKey to be in code repo) nor do I want it to be managed by our build automation (again, because *reasons*)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of the methods you specified are great. Our recommendation is to use a web.config app setting and using this in the global.asax.cs for standard initialization. No telemetry will be sent before the initlization as we hook into OnBeginRequest().

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics#a-namedynamic-ikeya-dynamic-instrumentation-key

Another method that might work well is to set the `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY` environment variable as it's picked up by the SDK. Of course that depends on if you have multiple apps on the same machine.

https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/blob/v2.2.0/src/Core/Managed/Net40/Extensibility/Implementation/TelemetryConfigurationFactory.cs#L22

Answer (score 14):

Here is the implementation that I am currently using, and it seems to work. However, I had other implementations that seemed to set the iKey either too early or too late as it seemed it would use the iKey in the physical `web.config` file deployed to Azure instead of pulling from the **Application settings** tab from the Portal. Are there better options to do this in a best practice sort of way?

**ApplicationInsights.config**

```
<!-- Find the following node and *remove* it. It will have a GUID in it.
     If you leave this, you may receive some errors even with all of the
     other changes. -->
<InstrumentationKey>{GUID HERE}</InstrumentationKey>
```

**Global.asax.cs**

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        // Add this first line below
        Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey =
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ai:InstrumentationKey"];

        // Showing the rest of this so you can see the order of operations
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        AutomapperConfig.Init();
    }
```

**web.config**

```
<!-- Add the following to <appSettings> and put your iKey value in here. -->
<add key="ai:InstrumentationKey" value="*****" />
```

**_Layout.cshtml** (in the `<head>` section of the HTML. NOTE TO FUTURE READERS: I recommend you don't use this entire snippet but instead just use the line that begins `instrumentationKey:` and integrate that line into whatever the modern version is for the rest of this JS snippet!):

```
<script type = 'text/javascript' >
    var appInsights=window.appInsights||function(config)
    {
        function r(config){ t[config] = function(){ var i = arguments; t.queue.push(function(){ t[config].apply(t, i)})} }
        var t = { config:config},u=document,e=window,o='script',s=u.createElement(o),i,f;for(s.src=config.url||'//az416426.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/a/ai.0.js',u.getElementsByTagName(o)[0].parentNode.appendChild(s),t.cookie=u.cookie,t.queue=[],i=['Event','Exception','Metric','PageView','Trace','Ajax'];i.length;)r('track'+i.pop());return r('setAuthenticatedUserContext'),r('clearAuthenticatedUserContext'),config.disableExceptionTracking||(i='onerror',r('_'+i),f=e[i],e[i]=function(config, r, u, e, o) { var s = f && f(config, r, u, e, o); return s !== !0 && t['_' + i](config, r, u, e, o),s}),t
    }({
        instrumentationKey:'@(Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey)'
    });

    window.appInsights=appInsights;
    appInsights.trackPageView();
</script>
```

Comment: Despite having provided an answer to my own question here, I hope others can provide better answers. I will accept your answer instead of mine if you can improve it. :-)