# How can I change the TraceLevel for an Azure App Service without redeploying it?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights, tracelistener

I am using Application Insights in an MVC 5 application that I deploy to an Azure App Service (formerly known as an "Azure Web Site"). I have Application Insights setup to be a Trace Listener. It all works well - I am using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42257315/294863).

My next need is to be able to control the `TraceLevel` setting without redeploying the site. I am mostly likely going to keep it at `Warning` on a 24/7 basis but if something funny or interesting is happening, I'd like to drop it down to Info or Verbose. It is this specific changing of the setting that I'm asking about. So my questions:

1. Is there a built-in way to change/toggle this without any downtime or deployments?
2. Is there a best practice way to accomplish this regardless of what the answer is to the previous question? Really looking to avoid hiccups/downtime as I toggle this, although if I must suffer a hiccup then that will still be better than a redeployment.

Note: I'm tagging this with Application Insights but I don't think it really matters what my trace listeners are.

Comment: Where are you setting TraceLevel now?

Comment: @paulwhit In the web.config: `<configuration><system.diagnostics><switches><add name="mySwitch" value="4" />` as per: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelevel(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this page:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log

> Unlike changing the web.config file, enabling Application diagnostics
>   or changing diagnostic log levels does not recycle the app domain that
>   the application runs within.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. This link tells me to switch toggles to "On" in order to add logging to my system and to control that new logging. That's not what I'm trying to do. I already have functional logging via trace listeners even though all of those toggles are turned off. I don't want to add additional logging - I just want to control the logging that I currently have, specifically changing the TraceLevel on my current logging.

Comment: I understood your question, but to avoid downtime this is the only way I found that avoid that.

Comment: I'll attempt this even with the negative consequences of adding additional/undesired logging and report back on whether or not it is adequately controlling my existing trace listeners.

Comment: This is far from what I was hoping to accomplish but I don't know of a better option at this time. Hopefully a better answer pops up. Until then, I'm accepting this answer.