# Application insights configuration in asp.net 4.8 web application

Tags: asp.net, azure, logging, web-applications, azure-application-insights

how can we configure application insights in asp.net 4.8 web application which has the entry point as **global.asax.cs** I need to pull out the logging in separate project and use Logger factor with **Microsoft.Extensions.Logging**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you already created a ***4.8 Web Application***. Follow the workaround to add Application Insights in your Web Application Project.

#### Workaround follows:

Install the Application Insights Package **Microsoft.ApplicationInsights** in your application using NuGet Package Manager.

[image]

**Configure Application insights in your Web Applicaiton:**

Right click of your project and click **Configure Application Insights**

[image]

It will ask you to choose ***Configure Application Insights*** either **local** or **Azure**. Choose as per your requirement.

[image]

It will configure your Web App into Application Insights. It adds the **ApplicationInsights.config** file which contains the configuration of Application Insights.

[image]

After the configuration done we can see the telemetry data in Application Insights

#### Results

[image]

#### References:

1. [Using pageview to collect telemetry data in pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42257294/configurable-application-insights-instrumentation-key) using Adding Instrumentation key in web.config
2. [Using Application Insights in global.aspx](https://github.com/dzimchuk/azure-app-insights/blob/master/C#/MyFixIt/Global.asax.cs)

Comment: this does the Magic logging which is fine as all the logs are getting into telemetry but as using Global.axax.cs need to use the propertyContext to enrich the log context and also configure the instrumentationkey via code which I did using `TelemetryConfiguration.Active.ConnectionString`
But I need to do the custom logging and as using asax.cs file and the database dao I can I write I custom logging in the code